# What do Ubuntu-Standard and Ubuntu-Server packages do?

Tags: 20.04

I recently installed ubuntu-server with kde-plasma for my new daily driver and all I really need is a browser, steam, discord, and spotify.

So I was going through packages figuring out what I should uninstall and I saw these really vague package names, ubuntu-standard and ubuntu-server.

What are these used for, what do they contain, and are they necessary for daily desktop use?

Answer (score 3):

The `ubuntu-standard` and `ubuntu-server` packages are both *metapackages*.

- They contain no software.
- They *depend* upon a set of other packages. That's their real job.

For example, let's take a look at the dependencies of `ubuntu-standard`. You can see that it pulls in a set of basic system utilities and tools: Busybox, cron, dnsutils, logrotate, man-db, etc.

```
$ apt depends ubuntu-standard
ubuntu-standard
  Depends: busybox-static
  Depends: cpio
    cpio:i386
  Depends: cron
    bcron
    cron:i386
  Depends: dmidecode
    dmidecode:i386
  Depends: dnsutils
    bind9-dnsutils:i386
    bind9-dnsutils
  Depends: dosfstools
  Depends: ed
    ed:i386
  Depends: file
    file:i386
  Depends: ftp
    ftp-ssl
  Depends: hdparm
  Depends: info
    info:i386
  Depends: iptables
    iptables:i386
  Depends: language-selector-common
  Depends: libpam-systemd
  Depends: logrotate
  Depends: lshw
  Depends: lsof
  Depends: ltrace
  Depends: man-db
    man-db:i386
  Depends: mime-support
  Depends: parted
    parted:i386
  Depends: pciutils
    pciutils:i386
  Depends: popularity-contest
  Depends: psmisc
    psmisc:i386
  Depends: rsync
    rsync:i386
  Depends: strace
  Depends: time
    time:i386
  Depends: usbutils
    usbutils:i386
  Depends: wget
    wget:i386
  Recommends: apparmor
  Recommends: bash-completion
  Recommends: command-not-found
  Recommends: friendly-recovery
  Recommends: iputils-tracepath
  Recommends: irqbalance
    gce-compute-image-packages
  Recommends: manpages
  Recommends: mtr-tiny
  Recommends: nano
  Recommends: ntfs-3g
  Recommends: openssh-client
    openssh-client:i386
  Recommends: plymouth
  Recommends: plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
  Recommends: tcpdump
  Recommends: telnet
  Recommends: ufw
  Recommends: update-manager-core
  Recommends: uuid-runtime
    uuid-runtime:i386
```

Comment: I'm coming from debian where there are pretty much zero packages installed at the beginning, so what would happen if I were to remove ubuntu-server?
I was looking at removing cloud-init package but that also removes ubuntu-server. Since I am using this as a desktop, would it do any harm?

Comment: You can remove metapackages; they contain no software. However, removal makes all dependent packages eligible for autoremoval. Since you have Debian experience, you likely already know what to do about that.